# oracle subquery in keyword is slow on 12c

Tags: oracle, subquery

compared to 11g, 12c (currently using 12.1.0.2 version) in keyword is so slow.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    DATA_TABLE WHERE
    OID IN (
        SELECT OID FROM ID_TABLE WHERE (condition)
    )
```

result

- 11g : under 1 sec
- 12c : over 10 sec

below query is fast enough in both 11g and 12c (to let you know real problem is 'in subquery' query

```
SELECT OID FROM ID_TABLE WHERE (condition)
```

I can solve this problem with changing query as below

```
SELECT * FROM 
    DATA_TABLE D,
    (
        SELECT OID FROM ID_TABLE WHERE (condition)
    ) O
WHERE D.OID = O.OID
```

result

- 11g : under 1 sec
- 12c : under 1 sec

OR

```
SELECT * FROM 
    DATA_TABLE WHERE
    OID IN (
        "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD, "EE"
    )
```

result

- 11g : under 1 sec
- 12c : under 1 sec

Problem is only on 'in sub query'. INDEX is well made both table.
Have Anyone solved this problem?

Comment: Problem is not in IN Clause but in this query may be, SELECT OID FROM ID_TABLE WHERE (condition). So provide ID_table structure with index detail. How many rows are in table, you may trying using DISTINCT keywork with OID.

Comment: I cannot provide structure now BUT i can tell that SELECT OID FROM ID_TABLE WHERE (condition) was same responding speed as 11g. I'll try DISTINCT key word tmrw thanks

Comment: Just to eliminate the possibility, can you please replace `SELECT OID FROM ID_TABLE` with `SELECT ID_TABLE.OID FROM ID_TABLE` and confirm you get the same performance results?

Comment: I think I'm diggin wrong point. I made new post please check this. stackoverflow.com/questions/34623779/

Answer (score 0):

You would have to provide the explain plans to better assess why one is performing better than the other.  But, in general, you can get better, or at least, more predictible results for this type of query by changing the `IN` condition to an `EXISTS` condition instead:

```
select *
  from data_table t1
 where exists (select null
                 from id_table t2
                where t2.oid = t1.oid
                  and (other conditions))
```

Comment: Can you substantiate that claim?

Comment: See https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:953229842074

Comment: i'll try and read yours kind answer and article. but still cannot figure out why 12c is much slower than 11g.

Comment: Downvoted because I believe your claim to be outdated.  The link you provided was a question from 2000.  Today, Oracle is smart enough to rewrite an `IN` as an `EXISTS` when the table sizes involved warrant it.

Comment: I think I'm diggin wrong point. I made new post please check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34623779/oracle-same-query-but-different-plan-in-11g-and-12c