# oracle - same query but different plan in 11g and 12c

Tags: oracle, optimization, oracle11g, pagination, oracle12c

This Question is relative to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34609799/oracle-subquery-in-keyword-is-slow-on-12c).
This is code i try to use in 12c

```
  SELECT * FROM DMProgDate_00001
  WHERE 1=1
  AND ProgressOID IN ( 
    SELECT P.OID FROM (
      SELECT OID FROM (
        SELECT A.OID, ROWNUM as seqNum FROM (
          SELECT OID FROM DMProgress_00001 
            WHERE 1=1
            AND Project = 'Moho'
            AND Phase = 'Procurement'
            AND Displine = 'Q340'
            ORDER BY actCode
          ) A
          WHERE ROWNUM <= 20
      ) WHERE seqNum > 0
    ) P
  );
```

- result

  11g : under 1 sec

  12c : over 8 sec

This is the query plan in 11g
[image]

This is the query plan in 12c
[image]

When I take out all pagination code (like below). query in 12c is fast enough as 11g BUT need pagination query.

```
  SELECT  * FROM DMProgDate_00001
  WHERE 1=1
  AND ProgressOID IN ( 
    SELECT P.OID FROM (
          SELECT OID FROM DMProgress_00001 
            WHERE 1=1
            AND Project = 'Moho'
            AND Phase = 'Procurement'
            AND Displine = 'Q340'
            ORDER BY actCode
    ) P
  );
```

This is the query (without pagination) plan in 12c
[image]

I tried OFFSET .. key word ( only 12c support) and optimizer_features_enable('11.2.0.4') but same result as above ( over 8 sec).

We need to support both 11g and 12c and I know some detour to fix this problem ( in  [my pre-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34609799/oracle-subquery-in-keyword-is-slow-on-12c)) BUT don't want to keep it as same query code. Is there any option or setting that can fix this qeustion?

---

added query plan as text
(they are different table name but are same table structure and contents)

```
12c - over 3 sec
Plan hash value: 3742986389

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name             | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |                  |     1 |   153 |   204   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER              |                  |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL  | DMPROGDATE_00001 |     1 |   153 |   102   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |   FILTER             |                  |       |       |            |          |
|*  4 |    COUNT STOPKEY     |                  |       |       |            |          |
|*  5 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| DMPROGRESS_00001 |    26 |  2288 |   102   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   1 - filter( EXISTS (<not feasible>)
   3 - filter("OID"=:B1)
   4 - filter(ROWNUM<=20)
   5 - filter("PROJECT"='Moho' AND "PHASE"='Procurement' AND "DISPLINE"='Q340')

Note
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
   - 1 Sql Plan Directive used for this statement





11g - 0.01 sec

Plan hash value: 833434956
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name             | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |                  |    13 |  1157 |    57   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN RIGHT SEMI|                  |    13 |  1157 |    57   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   VIEW               | VW_NSO_1         |     3 |    81 |    34   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    COUNT STOPKEY     |                  |       |       |            |          |
|*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| DMPROGRESS_00037 |     3 |    99 |    34   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL  | DMPROGDATE_00037 |  7388 |   447K|    22   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("PROGRESSOID"="OID")
   3 - filter(ROWNUM<=20)
   4 - filter("DISPLINE"='Q340' AND "PHASE"='Procurement' AND "PROJECT"='Moho')
```

Comment: Is the SQL generated by a visual tool? Do you have the option to override the SQL? (Reason why I am asking is because there are more efficient ways of writing this).

Comment: I'm using Oracle SQL Delvoper and it support to change db connection by selecting list.

Comment: Please run `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR your_sql_query`, and then  run `SELECT * FROM TABLE( DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY )` both on11.2g and 12c, and then copy and paste their result **as plain text**, not as bitmaps. Bitmaps are very hard to read. Thank you.

Comment: `... FROM (SELECT ..., ROWNUM as seqNum FROM ...) WHERE seqNum > 0` I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, `seqNum` will always be greater than zero.

Comment: It's dynamic query made by ibatis so the numbers (0, 20) can be changed like (20, 40) etc

Answer (score 0):

The execution plan chosen by the optimizer chosen can vary greatly even between two environments of the same version, not just 11g and 12c. It depends on many factors, but mostly:

- Number of rows in the table (are they similar between envs?)
- What indexes are present (do both dbs have the exact same indexes?)
- Are there stats for the table and the indexes, and how up to date are they? If not up-to-date, please gather stats for the tables *and* the the indexes.

If you can post these details I can provide a more helpful answer.

Also, the code looks like auto generated, if you are at liberty to modify them, based on the details, we can suggest a rewritten query and/or hints.

If you cannot modify the code, you can force a plan with SQL Plan Management (SPM) - export from the db where it runs faster and import into the other db.

*UPDATE*

Use this simplified version of the SQL to generate the plan:

```
SELECT * FROM DMProgDate_00001
 WHERE ProgressOID IN ( 
   SELECT OID FROM DMProgress_00001 
    WHERE Project = 'Moho'
      AND Phase = 'Procurement'
      AND Displine = 'Q340'
      AND ROWNUM <= 20
    ORDER BY actCode
  );
```

Comment: I can tell that 1. they are same number of rows in the table. 2. both tables have same indexes. 3. don't get it 'up-to-date' mean. they were made different time (made 3month ago for 11g, made 2days ago for 12c). Do you want to see V$INSTANCE table infomation?

Comment: In SQLDeveloper, right click the table and select Gather Stats. If you do not have the privileges, get a DBA to do it. Then run the query again, capturing the plan like @kordirko mentioned.